# Trouble with output in Do/While loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nested-loops, do-while

I am having issues with one of my outputs in my program. The issue stems from one of my outputs bypassing the nested do/while loop that is inside another do/while loop. I can put that first output statement inside the nested do/while loop. The problem with doing that is it will give me two output messages rather than one based on my calculations.  Unfortunately the program is kind of long since everything is in main.

```
import java.util.Scanner;   //CAPTURES USERS INPUT VIA THE KEYBOARD

public class practice
{

public practice()
{

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    char response = 0; //STORES USERS RESPONSE
    int attempt = 1; //LOOP CONTROL VARIABLE FOR OUTER DO WHILE LOOP
    int attempts = 1; //LOOP CONTROL VARIABLE FOR INNER DO WHILE LOOP
    double grossAnnualIncome = 0.0; //STORES USERS GROSS ANNUAL INCOME
    double annualTuition = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL TUITION PAYMENTS
    double annualCharity = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL DONATIONS TO CHARITY
    double homeMortgage = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL HOME MORTGAGE PAYMENTS
    double healthCredit = 0.0; //STORES USERS HEALTH INSURANCE CREDIT
    double annualAfterTaxes = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL INCOME AFTER TAXES
    double monthlyAfterTaxes = 0.0; //STORES USERS MONTHLY INCOME AFTER TAXES
    double taxOwed = 0.0; //STORES USERS TAX RATE AT A FIXED RATE OF 17%
    double taxableIncome = 0.0; //STORES USERS TAXABLE INCOME
    double taxCredits = 0.0; //STORES ALL OF THE USERS TAX CREDITS ADDED TOGETHER

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //ALLOWS THE USER TO ENTER THEIR CURRENT TAX INFORMATION

    do
    {
        do
        {

        System.out.print( "\nPlease enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  " ); //PROMPT 1
        grossAnnualIncome = input.nextDouble();

            if( grossAnnualIncome > 0 )
            {

            System.out.print( "\nPlease enter your annual tuition and expenses for higher education or 0 for none:  ");
            annualTuition = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print( "\nPlease enter your annual charitable contributions or 0 for none:  ");
            annualCharity = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print( "\nPlease enter the annual interest paid for your home mortgage or 0 for none:  ");
            homeMortgage = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();

            System.out.print( "\nDid you purchase health insurance through your employer or outside the workplace?"
              + " Enter 'Y' or 'N':  ");
        response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);


                if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y' )
                {

                System.out.print( "\nAre you filing as a family?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  "); //PROMPT 6
                response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

                    if ( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y' )
                    {

                    healthCredit = 3500;
                    }

                else
                {

                    if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'N' )
                        {

                        System.out.print( "\nAre you filing as single?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  "); //PROMPT 7
                        response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

                        }

                            if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y')
                            {

                            healthCredit = 2000;
                            }

                }

                }
                else
                {

                healthCredit = 0;
                }

                System.out.printf( "\nAre the following entries correct?\n\n"
                            + "Gross Annual Income:  $%,.0f\n\n"
                            + "Deductions: \n"
                            + "\tHigher Education:  %,.0f\n"
                            + "\tCharitable Contributions:  %,.0f\n"
                            + "\tHome Mortgage Interest:  %,.0f\n"
                            + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit:  %,.0f\n\n", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition,                                    annualCharity, homeMortgage, healthCredit);

                System.out.print( "\nEnter 'Y' or 'N': ");
                response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }

            if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y')
        {

            --attempts;

        }

        }while( attempts == 1);


                //CALCULATIONS
    taxableIncome  = grossAnnualIncome - taxCredits;
        taxOwed = taxableIncome * .17; //TAKES TAXABLE INCOME AND MULTIPLIES IT BY A 17% FLAT TAX RATE
        annualAfterTaxes = grossAnnualIncome - taxOwed; //TAKES USERS GROSS ANNUAL INCOME SUBTRACTED BY 17% TAX BRACKET
        monthlyAfterTaxes  = annualAfterTaxes  / 12; //DIVIDES THE USERS ANNUAL GROSS AFTER TAXES BY 12 FOR MONTHLY GROSS
        taxCredits = annualTuition + annualCharity + homeMortgage + healthCredit; //ADDS UP THE USERS TOTAL ANNUAL TAX

    if( grossAnnualIncome == 0 )
    {

    System.out.print( "\nYou earned no income so you owe no taxes!" ); //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME EQUALS ZERO OUTPUT
    input.nextLine();
    }

    else if(grossAnnualIncome <= taxCredits )
    {

    System.out.print( "\nYOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES!" ); //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO TAX CREDITS OUTPUT
    }

    else
    {


            //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME GREATER THAN ZERO OUTPUT
    System.out.printf( "\n\nYOUR TAXES\n\n"
                    + "Gross Annual Income:  $%,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Deductions: \n"
                    + "\tHigher Education:  %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tCharitable Contributions:  %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHome Mortgage Interest:  %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit:  %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Tax at 17%%:  $%,.0f\n"
                    + "Annual Income After Tax:  $%,.0f\n"
                    + "Monthly Income After Tax:  $%,.0f", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition, annualCharity,
                       homeMortgage, healthCredit, taxOwed, annualAfterTaxes, monthlyAfterTaxes);

    }

 System.out.print( "\n\nDo you want to calculate taxes for someone else?  Enter 'Y' or 'N' ");
     response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'N')
    {

        --attempt;
    }

}while(attempt == 1);

System.exit(0);

}

}
```

Again I'm sorry for how long the code is.  The exact issue I am having is that when the user enters 0 at the first prompt(without entering the nested do/while loop) it just loops:

```
Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  0

Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  0

Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  0
```

Now if I move:

```
if( grossAnnualIncome == 0 )
{

System.out.print( "\nYou earned no income so you owe no taxes!" );
input.nextLine();
break;
}
```

into the nested do/while loop I get:

```
Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  0

You earned no income so you owe no taxes!
YOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES!
```

When it should only read the 1st output.

The Correct output should look like:

```
Please enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  0

You earned no income so you owe no taxes!
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have a chance right now to plug this into a compiler, but try changing the default value of `attempt` and `attempts` to `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Well it fixed one thing and messed up another. I'm on the right track I think with that. Might have to tweak the logic a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user enters '0' none of the inner if statements are hit, attempts will not change, so you keep running the same loop.

**update:**
Let me say first that this is horribly, horribly wrong, but this should work. I changed your loop control to a boolean, moved a couple of things around.  Besides the total lack of oop going on here (an entity class would work much better), your scanner input will behave unpredictably if the user selects enter.
This is by no means bulletproof.

```
import java.util.Scanner;   //CAPTURES USERS INPUT VIA THE KEYBOARD

public class PracticeFromStackOverFlow
{

public PracticeFromStackOverFlow()
{

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    char response = 0; //STORES USERS RESPONSE
    boolean outerLoop = true; //LOOP CONTROL VARIABLE FOR OUTER DO WHILE LOOP
    boolean innerLoop = true; //LOOP CONTROL VARIABLE FOR INNER DO WHILE LOOP
    double grossAnnualIncome = 0.0; //STORES USERS GROSS ANNUAL INCOME
    double annualTuition = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL TUITION PAYMENTS
    double annualCharity = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL DONATIONS TO CHARITY
    double homeMortgage = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL HOME MORTGAGE PAYMENTS
    double healthCredit = 0.0; //STORES USERS HEALTH INSURANCE CREDIT
    double annualAfterTaxes = 0.0; //STORES USERS ANNUAL INCOME AFTER TAXES
    double monthlyAfterTaxes = 0.0; //STORES USERS MONTHLY INCOME AFTER TAXES
    double taxOwed = 0.0; //STORES USERS TAX RATE AT A FIXED RATE OF 17%
    double taxableIncome = 0.0; //STORES USERS TAXABLE INCOME
    double taxCredits = 0.0; //STORES ALL OF THE USERS TAX CREDITS ADDED TOGETHER

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //ALLOWS THE USER TO ENTER THEIR CURRENT TAX INFORMATION

    while(outerLoop)
    {
        innerLoop = true; // reset this every time you 
        while(innerLoop) {

            System.out.print( "\nPlease enter your gross annual income or 0 for none:  " ); //PROMPT 1
            grossAnnualIncome = input.nextDouble();

            if( grossAnnualIncome > 0 ) {

                System.out.print( "\nPlease enter your annual tuition and expenses for higher education or 0 for none:  ");
                annualTuition = input.nextDouble();

                System.out.print( "\nPlease enter your annual charitable contributions or 0 for none:  ");
                annualCharity = input.nextDouble();

                System.out.print( "\nPlease enter the annual interest paid for your home mortgage or 0 for none:  ");
                homeMortgage = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine();

                System.out.print( "\nDid you purchase health insurance through your employer or outside the workplace?"
                        + " Enter 'Y' or 'N':  ");
                response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                healthCredit = 0;

                if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y' ) {

                    System.out.print( "\nAre you filing as a family?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  "); //PROMPT 6
                    response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);


                    if ( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y' ) {

                        healthCredit = 3500;
                    } else { // do you really need this?  

                        if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'N' ) {

                            System.out.print( "\nAre you filing as single?  Enter 'Y' or 'N':  "); //PROMPT 7
                            response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
                        }

                        if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y') {

                            healthCredit = 2000;
                        }

                    }

                } 

                System.out.printf( "\nAre the following entries correct?\n\n"
                        + "Gross Annual Income:  $%,.0f\n\n"
                        + "Deductions: \n"
                        + "\tHigher Education:  %,.0f\n"
                        + "\tCharitable Contributions:  %,.0f\n"
                        + "\tHome Mortgage Interest:  %,.0f\n"
                        + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit:  %,.0f\n\n", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition,                                    annualCharity, homeMortgage, healthCredit);

                System.out.print( "\nEnter 'Y' or 'N': ");
                response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

                if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'Y'){
                    innerLoop = false;

                }
            } else {
                innerLoop = false;
            }
        }


                //CALCULATIONS
    taxableIncome  = grossAnnualIncome - taxCredits;
        taxOwed = taxableIncome * .17; //TAKES TAXABLE INCOME AND MULTIPLIES IT BY A 17% FLAT TAX RATE
        annualAfterTaxes = grossAnnualIncome - taxOwed; //TAKES USERS GROSS ANNUAL INCOME SUBTRACTED BY 17% TAX BRACKET
        monthlyAfterTaxes  = annualAfterTaxes  / 12; //DIVIDES THE USERS ANNUAL GROSS AFTER TAXES BY 12 FOR MONTHLY GROSS
        taxCredits = annualTuition + annualCharity + homeMortgage + healthCredit; //ADDS UP THE USERS TOTAL ANNUAL TAX

    if( grossAnnualIncome == 0 ) {

        System.out.print( "\nYou earned no income so you owe no taxes!" ); //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME EQUALS ZERO OUTPUT
        input.nextLine();
    }

    else if(grossAnnualIncome <= taxCredits ) {
        System.out.print( "\nYOU OWE $0.00 IN TAXES!" ); //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO TAX CREDITS OUTPUT
    }

    else {


            //GROSS ANNUAL INCOME GREATER THAN ZERO OUTPUT
    System.out.printf( "\n\nYOUR TAXES\n\n"
                    + "Gross Annual Income:  $%,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Deductions: \n"
                    + "\tHigher Education:  %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tCharitable Contributions:  %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHome Mortgage Interest:  %,.0f\n"
                    + "\tHealth Insurance Tax Credit:  %,.0f\n\n"
                    + "Tax at 17%%:  $%,.0f\n"
                    + "Annual Income After Tax:  $%,.0f\n"
                    + "Monthly Income After Tax:  $%,.0f", grossAnnualIncome, annualTuition, annualCharity,
                       homeMortgage, healthCredit, taxOwed, annualAfterTaxes, monthlyAfterTaxes);

    }

    System.out.print( "\n\nDo you want to calculate taxes for someone else?  Enter 'Y' or 'N' ");
     response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    if( Character.toUpperCase(response) == 'N') {
        System.out.print( "Laters");
        outerLoop = false;
    }

}

System.exit(0);

}

}
```

Comment: So then I should move that If == 0 statement inside the nested do/while? My only issue is that it prints two statements instead of one as shown above.

Comment: I copied the code you have above, initialized attempts to 0 and ran it, I didn't get the extra msg.  That won't be completely correct, you have to fix the attempts logic - if you're using it for control, why not use a boolean value?

Comment: Any idea on how to get my last prompt on my outer do/while loop to work again? After typing 0 it will display the message and then should ask if you would like to do more taxes

Comment: Thanks for showing me what you meant by the boolean value for a control. Yeah, this program is anything but solid. For instance if you typo a number on a Y or N prompt it crashes. The specifications for the program don't say anything about these issues yet, but I'm sure as the class goes on and I move into Java 2 that will change. I see what you did to get the program to run, but I never thought about doing it this way, so I need to digest this information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That function is very hard to read. The first thing you should do is to refactor it out into methods. I'm sure you can implement it without needing nested loops like that. The time you spend trying to debug ugly loops like that will more than equal just breaking it to more manageable chunks which can much easier be understood.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing that should go in a comment, not an answer, no?

Comment: Yeah, I know the code is very undesirable. This is an assignment and my teacher wants everything in main for the time being. I have everything coded and spaced properly in JCreator, but it gets kind of ugly when I paste it over here.